# Mechanize returning 500 on valid URL?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to fetch a specific page with Mechanize:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
p agent.get("http://formitas.si")
```

but I get this:

```
`fetch': 500 => Net::HTTPInternalServerError for http://formitas.si/ -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
```

while the page opens fine in a browser. Why?

Comment: I used `wget` and got this:

--2014-03-12 09:30:43--  http://formitas.si/
Resolving formitas.si (formitas.si)... 212.44.99.132
Connecting to formitas.si (formitas.si)|212.44.99.132|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2014-03-12 09:30:44 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

Comment: The title is misleading. The problem isn't Mechanize returning an error, it's merely the messenger reporting the problem. The server is returning 500 on a valid URL requested by Mechanize.

Comment: I tried curl and it worked... so curl works and wget/Mechanize don't....

Comment: I'm getting a 500 in chrome. I think your confusion is that it doesn't look like an error page when it loads.

Comment: Wow you're right... I checked now and Chrome is really getting 500 in headers... strange that it shows the page though...

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem on the server. That's easy to tell because it's a 500-series error.

Here's HTTP request diagnostics 101:

Consider what would be different between a browser and Mechanize that a server could sense. You've got the request URL itself, and the headers that are sent as part of the HTTP request.

The URL itself is easy to visually check so that can be ruled out immediately if you've confirmed it's identical in both Mechanize and the browser.

That leaves the headers. Use a tool to check what headers your browser sends, then look to see what you're using with Mechanize. Make them match.

From experience, I suspect it's a case of the browser's signature, or the acceptable data-types, being different between the browser and Mechanize, and that site not knowing how to handle one or the other.

Comment: Yes, thank you... but it's interesting that curl doesn't work while wget and Mechanize don't... and also very interesting the above answer that makes Mechanize work by connecting straight to the IP address... What can we conclude from all that? I don't know yet.

Comment: I conclude that they're sniffing for signatures and banning based on those. They might be allowing cURL because they know what it is.

Comment: they actually return 500 to Chrome as well (see above)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've run into an issue with Mechanize being unable to resolve the DNS itself.

Though I'm fairly certain Mechanize uses Resolv to get the underlying site, I too was unable to get `agent.get('http://formitas.si')` to work.

Instead what I did was explicitly accessed the Resolv library and set the IP as what I access rather than the host name.

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'Resolv'

@agent = Mechanize.new
address = Resolv.getaddress "formitas.si"
page = @agent.get('http://' + address.to_s) # wouldn't let me use string interpolation on SO

pp page
```

Which ended up giving me this:

```
#<Mechanize::Page
 {url #<URI::HTTP:0x007f7f93ec7c68 URL:http://212.44.99.132/>}
 {meta_refresh}
 {title nil}
 {iframes}
 {frames}
 {links #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://www.parallels.com/plesk/">}
 {forms}>
```

Comment: but this approach is not useful when trying to fetch anything else than a root page... :( also if this works and normal approach returns 500 error, something seems to be broken in Mechanize :/

Comment: Whoa, you're trying to fetch other pages now?! That wasn't in the description! But all sarcasm aside I don't think I can be of much more help. Sites don't want you to scrape them more often than not, it's very likely not a mechanize issue but a preventative measure put in place by the site itself. Quick edit: You're probably best off using a full browser emulator like Watir/Selenium if you're having issues on the site with mechanize. They actually handle Javascript, so if the data is loaded that way, well then you can actually get it.

Comment: :)  ok...  but regarding this site... no, they're not trying to put measures against scraping in, they're just incompetent... they actually return 500 to Chrome as well (see above)... but Chrome still displays the site... it looks like that's how it works, didn't know that.